# php class method within method

Tags: php, zend-framework, php-7, object-oriented-analysis

If I want to access the public method, I can do that easily. But if I want to access the property within method, what should I do, and is it recommended??

Can I do something like this in php?

```
class Auth {
   public function check($user = false){
    $project = false; //make it somehow public
     if($user == 'user1'){
       $this->project = 1;
     }
   }
}
```

and than in some other place

```
$auth = new Auth();
$auth->check('user1')->project;
```

Just so you people know its possible here is the `Zend framework` code from

> `Zend-Authentication`

```
 if ($result->isValid()) {
            $this->getStorage()->write($result->getIdentity());
        }
```

Comment: typo `$this-project = 1;` should be `$this->project = 1;`

Answer (score 3):

```
class Auth
{
   protected $project;

   public function __constructor($project = false)
   {
        $this->project = $project;
   }

   public function check($user = false)
   {
     if($user == 'user1')
     {
       $this->project = 1;
     }

      return $this;
   }

   public function project()
   {
       return $this->project;
   }
}
```

then you can do the following:

```
$auth = new Auth();
$auth->check('user1')->project(); // returns 1
```

or if you want you can also set another default value for the `$project`in the constructor

```
$auth = new Auth($other_default_value);
$auth->check('user2')->project();  // returns $other_default_value
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe your question is basically regarding [Fluent Interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) or Method Chaining in conjunction with the magic method [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)

Attempting to run this:

```php
<?php
class Auth {
   public function check($user = false){
    $project = false; //make it somehow public
     if($user == 'user1'){
       $this->project = 1;
     }
   }
}

$auth = new Auth();
$auth->check('user1')->project;
```

Results in:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /in/Hi5Rc on line 13

because `$auth->check('user1')` returns NULL (or void) and NULL doesn't have a `project` property.

The first thing we require is for `$auth->check('user1')` to return something useful. Given that `$project` is a boolean and `$this->project` is an integer, it makes the most sense to just return `$project` and get the value.

```php
<?php
class Auth {
   public function check($user = false){
    $project = false; //make it somehow public
     if($user == 'user1'){
       $this->project = 1;
     }
    return $project;
   }
}

$auth = new Auth();
print_r($auth->check('user1'));
```

which results in :

> bool(false)

But that doesn't address your question about how to fluently access a nonpublic field or parameter.

It appears that you are operating under the misconception that these projects are taking *method scoped variables* like `$project` in your `check()` class and making them accessible. They are not.

Not even in your example of the [Zend-Authentication](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-authentication/blob/0b17e2cc636398b24740bf279443f8b00ab48be5/src/AuthenticationService.php#L121).

The field [`$storage`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-authentication/blob/0b17e2cc636398b24740bf279443f8b00ab48be5/src/AuthenticationService.php#L19) itself is protected, but it has public (fluent) [getters/setters](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-authentication/blob/0b17e2cc636398b24740bf279443f8b00ab48be5/src/AuthenticationService.php#L75-L94).

So, `$this->getStorage()` returns an instance of [`new Storage\Session()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-authentication/blob/0b17e2cc636398b24740bf279443f8b00ab48be5/src/AuthenticationService.php#L78) which has a public [`write()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-authentication/blob/0b17e2cc636398b24740bf279443f8b00ab48be5/src/Storage/Session.php#L112-L115).

Thus `$this->getStorage()->write()` works.

So lets take your example class and modify it a bit to demonstrate.

```php
<?php
class Project{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $active;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $description;

    public function __construct($name = 'Default', $active = false, $description = '')
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->active = $active;
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Project
     */
    public function setName(string $name): Project
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $active
     *
     * @return Project
     */
    public function setActive(bool $active): Project
    {
        $this->active = $active;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Project
     */
    public function setDescription(string $description): Project
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isActive(): bool
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function toArray(){
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'active' => $this->active,
            'description' => $this->description
        ];
    }

    public function toJson(){
        return json_encode($this->toArray());
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->toJson();
    }
}



class Auth {

    /**
     * @var Project
     */
    private $project;

    public function __construct($project = Null)
    {
        $this->project = is_null($project)? new Project() : $project;
    }

    public function check($user = false){
        if($user == 'user1'){
            $this->project->setName("Project: $user")->setActive(true)->setDescription("This project belongs to $user");
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Project $project
     *
     * @return Auth
     */
    public function setProject(Project $project): Auth
    {
        $this->project = $project;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Project
     */
    public function getProject(): Project
    {
        return $this->project;
    }

}

$auth = new Auth();
echo $auth->check('user1')->getProject();
```

now results in:

> {"name":"Project: user1","active":true,"description":"This project
>   belongs to user1"}

However, you wanted to access the **private** field as if it were a public field without using a defined getter/setter. So lets make some more changes to the `Auth` class.

```php
class Auth {

    /**
     * @var Project[]
     */
    private $private_project;

    public function __construct($project = Null)
    {
        $this->private_project = is_null($project)? new Project() : $project;
    }

    public function check($user = false){
        if($user == 'user1'){
            $this->private_project->setName("Project: $user")->setActive(true)->setDescription("This project belongs to $user");
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($name === 'project'){
            return $this->private_project;
        }
    }

}
```

Now you can fluently access the field as you requested:

```php
$auth = new Auth();
echo $auth->check('baduser')->project;
echo  "\n";
echo $auth->check('user1')->project;
```

results in:

> {"name":"Default","active":false,"description":""}
>
> {"name":"Project: user1","active":true,"description":"This project belongs to user1"}

Laravel's Eloquent models make great use of the [`__get()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/72f47ddde6154744e2d287160fdea598d0294afa/Eloquent/Model.php#L1219)function for accessing model fields dynamically. Laravel also makes great use of the [`__call()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=__call) magic method for fluency.

I hope that helps bring some clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create extra class properties and "preserve method chaining", what about [`yield`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php)?

```php
class Auth
{
   public function check($user = false)
   {
       $project = false; // make it somehow public

       if($user === 'user1'){
           (yield 'project' => $project); // making it public
       }

       return $this;
   }
}
```

Later on you can discover it as follows:

```php
$array = iterator_to_array($auth->check($user));
// array(1) { ["project"] => bool(false) }
```

But for this to use *you won't be able to use method chaining*, because you need to retrieve generator anyway, so better to revise approach for discovering the `$project`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add it as a class variable:

```
class Auth {
   public $project = false;

   public function check($user = false) {
     if($user == 'user1'){
       $this->project = 1;
     }
   }
}
```

The property is then available as follows:

```
$auth = new Auth ();
$auth->check ('user1');
echo $auth->project; // 1
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: $auth->project; works but $auth->check()->project; doesn't gives the error

Comment: OK, point made. I thought the syntax was given as a way to try and access a variable within a function. Since the user doesn't understand about class variables, my assumption was that they wouldn't understand the class returning an instance of itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Auth
{
    public $project;
    public function check($user = false)
    {
        $this->project = false;//make it somehow public
        if ($user == 'user1') {
            $this->project = 1;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}

$auth = new Auth();
var_dump($auth->check('user1')->project);
```

This will return you 1. The local variables defined in function are only accessbile inside the function not outside hence you need to define them globally

Comment: $auth->project; works but $auth->check()->project; doesn't 
gives the error

Comment: because $project is the property of class not function

Comment: a function doesn't have property.. property is for class .. so the class return instance of itself and thats why through the function you are able to access the property of the class. A function /method doesn't hold any property

Comment: haha, that was my question that it is not working. yours is not working either

Answer (score 0):

`$project` is a local variable in your case, visible within the scope of the `check` method. You could define it as a member:

```
class Auth {
   public $project = false;
   public function check($user = false){
     if($user == 'user1'){
       $this-project = 1;
     }
   }
}
```

However, it is recommendable to make the member `public` and reach it via a getter, which will check whether it was initialized and if not, initialize it:

```
class Auth {
   private $project = false;
   public getProject($user = false) {
      if ($this->project === false) {
          check($user);
      }
      return $this->project;
   }
   public function check($user = false){
     if($user == 'user1'){
       $this-project = 1;
     }
   }
}
```